# Can't pass in "%26" to a WebGet UriTemplate variable in a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, iis, ampersand, webget, uritemplate

I have a WCF service with this declared operation:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "Test/{*testString}")]
public String Test(String testString)
{
    return testString;
}
```

However when attempting to invoke the URL `Test/You%26Me`, IIS returns an error:

```
A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (&).
```

My goal is to allow an ampersand in the URI via its URL-Encoding: %26

The wildcard did not help. Is there any way to prevent this error without disabling security features?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [`RequestPathInvalidCharacters`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters.aspx) configuration property in Web.config avoiding used characters as follows:

```
<system.web>
   <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="<,>,*,:,\\" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: I forgot to specify that I'm not using .NET 4.0 yet -- is there a similar option for .NET 3.5?

Comment: I'm afraid the only option in 3.5 is to implement custom RequestValidator: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.util.requestvalidator.aspx