# C# MVC: Chrome using the action name to set inline PDF title

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, pdf

I have an action who displays a PDF in a new browser tab.

```
    public ActionResult Print()
    {
        var cd = new ContentDisposition
        {
            FileName ="something.pdf",
            Inline = true 
        };
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", cd.ToString());
        return File(reportResponse.Data.Document, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);

    }
```

The filename is working fine. When I download the file it has the name I want "something.pdf".

The problem is when google chrome opens the PDF in a new browser tab, it displays the controller action name (Print) as the title of the PDF. That's what I'm trying to change. I attached a picture for clarification.[image]

View code: 
Url.Action("Print", "Controller", new { area = "Area" }), new { @target = "_blank" }

Comment: Browsers (at least Chrome and Firefox) set title of the page from title metadata of pdf document. http://w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/PDF18.html

Comment: In my case, the PDF was a partial page to be displayed inline with other content. In MVC the title is set to the name of the action. In my case I just changed the action name to something generic. Still hoping to find a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

To the action method pass parameter of the file name and make sure parameter name is **'id'**.

View code:

`Url.Action("Print", "Controller", new { id = "filename", area = "Area" }), new { @target = "_blank" }`

Comment: Any chance to make this work without having the filename as `id` attribute? I have a numeric id (e.g. 1234) and both firefox/chrome show the pdf with those numeric id instead of filename. Altough `Inline = true` is set, your snippet download the pdf file instead of showing them inline.

Answer (score 2):

Adding to kodandarami's answer,

When you're passing a PDF file back from ASP.NET MVC, the page title **is set to the last url part of the route config used to get to your controller**.

Knowing this, you can dynamically name the title by setting up a parameter as part of the route config for your controller eg:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Print",
            "print/{pdfName}",
            new { controller = "Print", action = "Index", pdfName = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Then MVC will use this value instead as it considers it a separate page.

Use it in the url as
**"/print/this-is-my-pdf-title"** not **'/print?pdfName=this-is-my-pdf-title"**.

As a querystring parameter, MVC will just fall back to calling the PDF 'print'.

**Note:**
As mentioned in [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3103282),

IIS has more strict rules about forbidden characters when the text is before the query string '?' character. You are not allowed `<,>,*,%,&,:,\` ([See MS Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.configuration.httpruntimesection.requestpathinvalidcharacters?view=netframework-4.8))

Any of these characters, **even when encoded** will give you a '**Path is potentially dangerous**' 400 error.

Make sure to remove/replace these forbidden characters.

.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by using a iframe.

Create an action which fills the title and pdf url.

```
        public ActionResult ArticleSpecification(int ArticleID)
        {
            using (var context = new myEntities())
            {
                Article article = context.Article.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ArticleID == ArticleID);
                ViewData["Title"] = article.Code + " - " + article.Description;
                ViewData["PdfSource"] = "ArticleSpecificationPdf?ArticleID=" + article.ArticleID;
                return View("~/Views/Specification/pdfview.cshtml");
            }
        }
```

pdfview.cshtml: with a iframe to view the pdf and title.

```
@{
    Layout = "";
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
        <style>
            html, body, iframe {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
                border: 0;
            }
            body {
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <iframe src="@ViewData["PdfSource"]"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

The action to return the pdf content.

```
        public FileResult ArticleSpecificationPdf(int ArticleID)
        {
            using (var context = new myEntities())
            {
                PdfFile file = null;
                Article article = context.Article.FirstOrDefault(a => a.ArticleID == ArticleID);
                if (article != null && article.SpecificationPdfID != null)
                    file = context.PdfFile.FirstOrDefault(a => a.PdfFileID == article.SpecificationPdfID);
                return new FilePathResult(file.path, "application/pdf");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the following return statement:

```
return File(reportResponse.Data.Document, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, "something.pdf");
```

Comment: This downloads the file with that name rather than displaying it in browser